# Firebase - Associating Pictures to Users?

Tags: android, image, firebase-storage, user-profile

I am trying to use Firebase to associate uploaded photos to a User so they can be seen on their Profile. Currently it is uploading them to Storage but it doesn't seem to be necessarily associated to a User ID. Shouldn't they show in the "Database" section?

I have looked through https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files as well as https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files and some stackoverflow articles([Firebase storage structure example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267536/firebase-storage-structure-example)) and youtube vids

What I've specifically tried is to get the getCurentUser() to set it to a String and attach that to the image name so I could find it later, but I'm assuming there must be a simpler built-in way?

I login and then go to this RegisterPhotoActivity:

```
public class RegisterPhotoActivity extends Activity {

    Button uploadProfilePhoto;
    ImageView checkmarkImage, backArrowImage;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private static FirebaseUser currentUser;
    String currentUserString;

    private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE = 1;

    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registerphoto);

        uploadProfilePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadPhotoBTN);
        checkmarkImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.checkmarkImage);

        backArrowImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leftArrow);
        backArrowImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterPhotoActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        currentUser =
                auth.getCurrentUser();
        currentUserString = currentUser.toString();
        Log.i("CurrentUserString", currentUserString);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        //storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://timeclock-fc.appspot.com").child("20170702_174811.jpeg"); 
        //storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://timeclock-fc.appspot.com").child(currentUserString); 
        storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://timeclock-fc.appspot.com/images").child(currentUserString); 



        checkmarkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterPhotoActivity.this, RegisterBusinessActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        uploadProfilePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                handleChooseImage(view);
            }
        });

    }

    //END OF onCreate

    //Separate methods

    //Actually opens the CameraRoll
        public void handleChooseImage(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);  //then goes to onActivityResult
        }
        public void handleInsertData(View v) {

        }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if(requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i("RegisterActivity", "case 0");
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    Log.i("RegisterActivity", "selected image = " + selectedImage);
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
                    try {
                        imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(imageBitmap);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);  //was PNG
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterPhotoActivity.this, "reached onSuccess:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here are my Storage Rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /images {
         // Only an individual user can write to "their" images
      match /{userId}/{imageId} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

My Storage:
[image: Storage]

My Firebase Node where I'm expecting it to show:
[image: Firebase DB Node]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens automatically in your database when a photo gets uploaded to Storage. One option would be to add some code to `onSuccess` in your `OnSuccessListener` which gets the photo's download url and then writes it to your database under the relevant employee userID. Code might be something like:

```
 Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();       
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); 
 map.put("photoDownloadUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
 userRef.updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: I had not found that getDownloadUrl, that helped a lot thank you. Works! Only change I made was adding the userId to it: mDatabaseEmp.child(currentUser.getUid()).updateChildren(map);